# Android Studio Code Coverage Report is Different than Codecov.io

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, codecov

When I run the Code Coverage Report using Android Studio I get about 17.8% of Code coverage whereas on Codecov.io I am only getting only 10.69%

[image: Android Studio Coverage Report]

[image: Codecov Coverage Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom from [Codecov](https://codecov.io) here. Would you mind opening a ticket on our [community boards](https://community.codecov.io) so we can dig in deeper? I'll update here when we get a useable solution.

Comment: here is the link https://community.codecov.io/t/android-studio-code-coverage-report-is-different-than-codecov-io/2299